# Uploading apk to play store failing due to app version

Tags: android, google-play, release

The current app has version 28 and the new version I want to upload is 30. I uploaded an apk and then removed it after saving the release. Now when I try to upload a new apk with the version 30 the console says I have to upload a version higher than 30.

Comment: Up code version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That case you should increase Version by number one and to upload as version 31

Because your old version is 30.Playstore not allowed decrease the version.

so you should try version 31

Answer (score 4):

Yes , now you need to compulsory change the apk version 30+ as now they are not allowing the same version with previous one